# EXTJS container-/panel-layout via custom non-generic html template

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am looking for a nice way to apply custom layouts to panels. The idea is to give some html code and tell the items where they should be placed in the html. I tried all available config options that appear to have an effect on the matter, but so far without any success. So my question is whether there is a way to configure the desired behaviour or do I need to implement a custom subclass of layout for this? I am looking for a generic way that can be applied for any containercomponent without repeating boilerplate code every time I want to apply custom layout and without breaking the containment hierarchie so that stuff like .down(...) still works. Ideally I'm looking for a way to have this functionality not just for some markup given via the html-config, but for XTemplates in a way that embedded items survive update-calls. Thanks!

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.test.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.test',
title: 'Test',

html: [
    'This is <b>some</b> test <i>HTML</i><br>',
    'Here we have a button:<div id="myButton"></div>.<br>',
    'The button should rerender everytime the component\'s html is updated.<br>',
    '<br>',
    'And now to something completely different:',
    '<center> <div id="anotherPanel"></div></center>'],    
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'My Label',
        SOME_UNKNOWN_KEY:'#myButton'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Some contained panel',
        SOME_UNKNOWN_KEY:'#anotherPanel',
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
            html: '<center>The panel content</center>'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Nest further. The `html` on the outer panel should become a component with `html`. Then you're just laying out components. I wouldn't attempt to struggle in the other direction.

Comment: I don't see how this could work. I want to place the items **inside** the html. There are divs with ids in the html and i'd like to have the result look as if I had used the renderTo config. Unfortunately renderTo does not work when there's an enclosing container, but that's basically what I want to do.